# Linker error LNK2019 in boost asio http client code

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost-asio

I am trying to use boost asio library to implement an http client. But I am facing some linker error which I am not able to fix.

Here is the code

### yql_asio.cpp

```
#include "common.h"
#include "yql.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        int thread_num = 2;
        if ( argc > 1 )
            thread_num = boost::lexical_cast<int>(argv[1]);


        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        Yql yql_main(io_service, "http://www.google.com");
        yql_main.GetResponse();

        io_service.run();

    }
    catch(std::exception & e)
    {
        std::cerr<<e.what()<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

### yql.h

```
#ifndef YQL_H
#define YQL_H

#include "yql_conn.h"
#include "common.h"

typedef std::deque<io_service_ptr> ios_deque;

class Yql //: public boost::noncopyable
{
private:
    std::string m_url;
    std::string m_response;
    //boost::shared_ptr<Connection> m_conn;
    Connection *m_conn;
    boost::asio::io_service &io_service_;

public:
    Yql(boost::asio::io_service &io_service, std::string p_url);
    ~Yql(){}
    void GetResponse();
};


#endif
```

### yql.cpp

```
#include "yql.h"


Yql::Yql(boost::asio::io_service& io_services, std::string p_url) 
    : m_url(p_url)
    , io_service_(io_services)
{
    m_conn = new Connection(io_service_, p_url);
    //m_conn = Connection::create(io_service_, m_url);
}

void Yql::GetResponse()
{
    m_conn->start();
}
```

### yql_conn.h

```
#ifndef YQL_CONN_H
#define YQL_CONN_H

#include "common.h"
#include <map>

class Connection //: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Connection>
{
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Connection> pointer;

    static pointer create(ba::io_service & io_service, std::string p_url)
    {
        return pointer(new Connection(io_service, p_url));
    }

    Connection(ba::io_service & io_service, std::string p_url);

    /*ba::ip::tcp::socket& socket()
    {
        return socket_;
    } */

    void start();

private:

    /*void handle_browser_write(const bs::error_code & errc, size_t len);*/
    void handle_read_headers(const bs::error_code & errc, size_t len);
    void handle_server_write(const bs::error_code & errc, size_t len);
    void handle_server_read_headers(const bs::error_code & errc, size_t len);
    void handle_server_read_body(const bs::error_code & errc, size_t len);

    void start_connect();
    void start_write_to_server();
    void shutdown();

    void handle_resolve(const boost::system::error_code & err, ba::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator);
    void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code & err, ba::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator);

    ba::io_service& io_service_;
    ba::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
    ba::ip::tcp::resolver resolver_;
    //bool proxy_closed;
    //bool isPersistent;
    int32_t RespLen;
    int32_t RespReaded;

    //boost::array<char, 8192> bbuffer;
    boost::array<char, 8192> sbuffer;

    std::string m_response;

    std::string m_url;
    std::string m_headers;
    std::string m_new_url;
    std::string m_method;
    std::string m_req_version;
    std::string m_server;
    std::string m_port;
    //bool m_is_open;

    std::string fReq;

    typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> headersMap;
    headersMap reqHeaders, respHeaders;

    void parseHeaders(const std::string& h, headersMap& m);
};


#endif
```

### yql_conn.cpp

```
#include "yql_conn.h"

Connection::Connection(ba::io_service & io_service, std::string p_url)
    : io_service_(io_service)
    , socket_(io_service)
    , resolver_(io_service)
    //, proxy_closed(false)
    //, isPersistent(false)
    //, m_is_open(false)
    , m_url(p_url)
{
} //end of Connection()


void Connection::start() //called
{
    std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<"BEGINS"<<std::endl;

    m_headers.clear();
    reqHeaders.clear();
    respHeaders.clear();

    start_connect();

    //boost::asio::async_read(bsocket_, ba::buffer(bbuffer), ba::transfer_at_least(1),
    //  boost::bind(&Connection::handle_browser_read_headers,
    //              shared_from_this(),
    //              ba::placeholders::error,
    //              ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred) );

    std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<"ENDS"<<std::endl;
} //start() 


void Connection::start_connect() //called
{
    std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<"BEGINS"<<std::endl;
    m_server = "";
    //std::string port = "80";
    m_port = "80";
    boost::regex rHTTP("http://(.*?)(:(\\d+))?(/.*)");
    boost::smatch m;

    if ( boost::regex_search(m_url, m, rHTTP, boost::match_extra) )
    {
        m_server = m[1].str();
        if ( m[2].str() != "" )
        {
            m_port = m[3].str();
        }
        m_new_url = m[4].str();
    }

    if ( m_server.empty() )
    {
        std::cout<<"Can't parse URL "<<std::endl;
        return;
    }

    //if ( !m_is_open || (server != m_server) || (port != m_port) )
    /*if ( port != m_port) )
    {
        m_server = server;
        m_port = port;
    */  
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(m_server, m_port);

    resolver_.async_resolve(query, 
        boost::bind(&Connection::handle_resolve, this,//shared_from_this(),
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::iterator));
    //}
    /*else
    {
        start_write_to_server();
    }*/

    std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<"ENDS"<<std::endl;
}//start_connect() 


void Connection::handle_resolve(const boost::system::error_code & err,
                                    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator) //called
{
    std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<"BEGINS"<<std::endl;
    if ( !err )
    {
        std::cout<<"Remote address resolved..."<<std::endl;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *endpoint_iterator;
        socket_.async_connect(endpoint, boost::bind(&Connection::handle_connect,
                                            //shared_from_this(),
                                            this,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                            ++endpoint_iterator));
    }
    else
    {
        shutdown();
    }
    std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<"ENDS"<<std::endl;
} //handle_resolve()


void Connection::handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code & err, 
                boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator) //called
{
    std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<"BEGINS"<<std::endl;

    if ( !err )
    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint remote_host = socket_.remote_endpoint();
        boost::asio::ip::address remote_host_addr = remote_host.address();
        std::string addr_repr = remote_host_addr.to_string();
        std::cout<<"Connected to "<<addr_repr<<std::endl;
        //m_is_open = true;
        start_write_to_server();
    }
    else if ( endpoint_iterator != boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator())
    {
        socket_.close();
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *endpoint_iterator;
        socket_.async_connect(endpoint, boost::bind(&Connection::handle_connect, 
                                //shared_from_this(),
                                this,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                ++endpoint_iterator));
    }
    else
    {
        shutdown();
    }

    std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<"ENDS"<<std::endl;
} //handle_connect()


void Connection::start_write_to_server() //called
{
    std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<"BEGINS"<<std::endl;

    fReq = m_method;
    fReq += " ";
    //fReq += m_new_url;
    fReq += m_url;
    fReq += " HTTP/";
    fReq += "1.0";
    fReq += "\r\n";
    fReq += m_headers;

    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(fReq),
        boost::bind(&Connection::handle_server_write, this, //shared_from_this(), 
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    m_headers.clear();

    std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<"ENDS"<<std::endl;
} //start_write_to_server()


void Connection::handle_server_write(const bs::error_code & err, size_t len) //called
{
    std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<"BEGINS"<<std::endl;

    if ( !err )
    {
        std::cout<<"Bytes sent to server :: "<<len<<std::endl;
        boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(sbuffer), boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
            boost::bind(&Connection::handle_server_read_headers,
                        //shared_from_this(),
                        this,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred ) );
    }
    else
    {
        shutdown();
    }

    std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<"ENDS"<<std::endl;
} //handle_server_write


void Connection::handle_server_read_headers(const boost::system::error_code & err, size_t len) //called
{
    std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<"BEGINS"<<std::endl;

    if ( !err )
    {
        std::string::size_type idx;

        if ( m_headers.empty() )
            m_headers = std::string(sbuffer.data(), len);
        else
            m_headers += std::string(sbuffer.data(), len);

        idx = m_headers.find("\r\n\r\n");

        if ( idx == std::string::npos )
        {
            boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(sbuffer),
                                        boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
                                        boost::bind(&Connection::handle_read_headers,
                                            //shared_from_this(),
                                            this,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
        else
        {
            RespReaded = len - idx - 4;
            idx = m_headers.find("\r\n");
            std::string respString = m_headers.substr(0, idx);
            RespLen = -1;
            parseHeaders(m_headers.substr(idx+2), respHeaders);
            std::string reqConnString = "", respConnString = "";
            std::string respVersion = respString.substr(respString.find("HTTP/")+5,3);
            headersMap::iterator it = respHeaders.find("Content-Length");
            if ( it != respHeaders.end() )
                RespLen = boost::lexical_cast<int>(it->second);
            it = respHeaders.find("Connection");
            if ( it != respHeaders.end() )
                respConnString = it->second;
            it = respHeaders.find("Connection");
            if ( it != respHeaders.end() )
                reqConnString = it->second;

            //isPersistent = (
            //  ((m_req_version == "1.1" && reqConnString != "close") ||
            //   (m_req_version == "1.0" && reqConnString == "keep-alive" )) &&
            //  ((respVersion == "1.1" && respConnString != "close") ||
            //   (respVersion == "1.0" && respConnString == "kepp-alive" )) &&
            //  RespLen != -1 );

            std::cout<<"Header Received :: "<<m_headers;

            boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(sbuffer, len),
                boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
                boost::bind(&Connection::handle_server_read_body,
                                //shared_from_this(),
                                this,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

            //boost::asio::async_write(bsocket_, boost::asio::buffer(m_headers),
            //  boost::bind(&Connection::handle_browser_write,
            //              shared_from_this(),
            //              boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            //              boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        shutdown();
    }

    std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<"ENDS"<<std::endl;
} //handle_server_read_headers


void Connection::handle_server_read_body(const bs::error_code & err, size_t len) //called
{
    std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<"BEGINS"<<std::endl;

    if ( !err || err == boost::asio::error::eof )
    {
        std::cout<<"Data received :: "<<std::string(sbuffer.begin(), sbuffer.end())<<std::endl;
        RespReaded += len;

        boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(sbuffer, len),
        boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
        boost::bind(&Connection::handle_server_read_body,
                        //shared_from_this(),
                        this,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        //if ( err == boost::asio::error::eof )
        //  proxy_closed = true;
        //boost::asio::async_write(bsocket_, boost::asio::buffer(sbuffer, len),
        //  boost::bind(&Connection::handle_browser_write,
        //              shared_from_this(),
        //              boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        //              boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
    else
    {
        shutdown();
    }

    std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<"ENDS"<<std::endl;
} //handle_server_read_body

void Connection::handle_read_headers(const bs::error_code & err, size_t len)
{
    if (!err)
    {
        std::cout<<"Bytes Received ... :: "<<len<<std::endl;
        if ( m_headers.empty())
        {
            m_headers = std::string(sbuffer.data(), len);
        }
        else
        {
            m_headers += std::string(sbuffer.data(), len);
        }
        if ( m_headers.find("\r\n\r\n") == std::string::npos )
        {
            boost::asio::async_read(socket_, ba::buffer(sbuffer), ba::transfer_at_least(1),
                boost::bind(&Connection::handle_read_headers, 
                            //shared_from_this(),
                            this,
                            ba::placeholders::error,
                            ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
        else
        {
            std::string::size_type idx = m_headers.find("\r\n");
            std::string reqString = m_headers.substr(0, idx);
            m_headers.erase(0, idx+2);

            idx = reqString.find(" ");
            if ( idx == std::string::npos )
            {
                std::cout<<"Bad first line : "<<reqString<<std::endl;
                return;
            }

            m_method = reqString.substr(0, idx);
            reqString = reqString.substr(idx+1);
            idx = reqString.find(" ");
            if ( idx == std::string::npos )
            {
                std::cout<<"Bad first line of request : "<< reqString << std::endl;
                return;
            }

            m_url = reqString.substr(0,idx);
            m_req_version = reqString.substr(idx+1);
            idx = m_req_version.find("/");
            if ( idx == std::string::npos )
            {
                std::cout<<"Bad first line of request : "<<reqString<<std::endl;
                return;
            }

            m_req_version = m_req_version.substr(idx+1);
            parseHeaders(m_headers, reqHeaders);

            //start_connect();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        shutdown();
    }
}


void Connection::parseHeaders(const std::string & h, headersMap & hm)
{
    std::string str(h);
    std::string::size_type idx;
    std::string t;

    while ( (idx=str.find("\r\n")) != std::string::npos )
    {
        t = str.substr(0, idx);
        str.erase(0, idx+2);
        if ( t == "" )
            break;
        idx = t.find(": ");
        if ( idx == std::string::npos )
        {
            std::cout<<"Bad header line: "<<t<<std::endl;
            break;
        }

        hm.insert(std::make_pair(t.substr(0, idx), t.substr(idx+2)));
    }
} //parseHeaders


void Connection::shutdown()
{
    std::cout<<"Closing socket..."<<std::endl;
    socket_.close();
    //bsocket_.close();
} //shutdown
```

### common.h

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>

#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

#include <boost/regex.hpp>

#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/utility.hpp>

namespace ba=boost::asio;
namespace bs=boost::system;

typedef boost::shared_ptr<ba::ip::tcp::socket> socket_ptr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<ba::io_service> io_service_ptr;

#endif
```

The Linker Errors are

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: yql_asio, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 20-03-2013 AM 1:06:33.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\yql_asio.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  yql_conn.h
1>  Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately. For example:
1>  - add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to the compiler command line; or
1>  - add _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to your project's Preprocessor Definitions.
1>  Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 (i.e. Windows XP target).
1>  yql_conn.cpp
1>  Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately. For example:
1>  - add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to the compiler command line; or
1>  - add _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to your project's Preprocessor Definitions.
1>  Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 (i.e. Windows XP target).
1>  yql_asio.cpp
1>  Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately. For example:
1>  - add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to the compiler command line; or
1>  - add _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to your project's Preprocessor Definitions.
1>  Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 (i.e. Windows XP target).
1>  Yql.cpp
1>  Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately. For example:
1>  - add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to the compiler command line; or
1>  - add _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to your project's Preprocessor Definitions.
1>  Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 (i.e. Windows XP target).
1>  Generating Code...
1>Debug\yql_conn.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored
1>Yql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Connection::Connection(class boost::asio::io_service &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (??0Connection@@QAE@AAVio_service@asio@boost@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Yql::Yql(class boost::asio::io_service &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (??0Yql@@QAE@AAVio_service@asio@boost@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>Yql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Connection::start(void)" (?start@Connection@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Yql::GetResponse(void)" (?GetResponse@Yql@@QAEXXZ)
1>C:\Users\asit\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\yql_asio\Debug\yql_asio.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:31.88
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Please help me to fix the bug.

Comment: Ensure that 'yql_conn.cpp' gets compiled.

Comment: all cpp files were compiled.

Comment: But you forgot to link yql_conn.obj. Also, you did a really bad job of simplifying the problem. I'm pretty sure not every line of the above code was necessary to reproduce the error.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [sscce](http://sscce.org) with a single file, not five of them.

Comment: Is the LNK4042 warning relevant here? I'm not a Windows guy so I really don't know, when building with gcc and clang I prefer to compile cleanly with warnings flagged as errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two LNK2019 errors.  The first one says that it can not find the 2 argument connection constructor.  The 2nd one says that it can not find the start method from the connection class.  There is also a LNK4042 warning.  This warning suggests that you became aware of the problem with linking to your Connection class, which is defined in yql_conn.h and yql_conn.cpp and you then tried to explicitly link to the file.  Your explicit linking is probably correct, but since there are two versions floating around, it picked up the other one and ignored the explicit one.  That would explain why you are getting this warning.

So, I suspect the problem is one of versioning or there is another Connection class that was written by someone else that you are picking up.  You probably defined the connection class somewhere else - either in a different file or the same file but in a different folder.  The older version of this file probably does not have the Connection constructor defined properly and no definition for the start method - which would explain the unresolved link errors.  So, what you might try doing is go to yql.h or yql.cpp and right click on Connection.  Select go to definition.  If it takes you to the file that has a definition for start, and the constructor looks right, then try right clicking on Connection again and choose Find All References.  You can also try searching for Connection in all files as well.  You might need to remove the old files and insert the new ones into the project, or you can simply copy and paste the code from the newer file into the files the project is using and then get rid of the explicit link.